# How I know at design time, what component has focus

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to know at design time, what component is focused (it means, was clicked and is outlined by the eight tiny blue baloons). I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Using OTA (Open Tools Api) you can get to know many of such things. But at what moment would you like to know that? I mean, what is your trigger, how are you going to ask this from the IDE?

Comment: Well, I'll try to clarify. At design time, I drop my `TCustomComponent` on a form, then when mouse pointer is over, I outline it with a dashed line and when the mouse pointer leaves, I erase that dashed line. I want to avoid this behavoir  (still at design time) when the component has focus.

Comment: I know this is a bad question, but: why? What do you need to change standard behaviour for?

Comment: Hi `GolezTrol`. Would you please show me how can I know at design time wich component has focus using OTA? Thanks in advance.